# Check arguments given to another callable argument

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a function to which I give a callable. In my test, I would like to check the called and the arguments given to this function.

As the function is given in argument and not imported, I cannot mock it (or I didn't find the correct way to do it).

Yet, I mock a typing function and because it is not used at runtime, I know it won't break anything.

It works well but I don't find it really Pythonic.

Is there another way to give to a function with I can check the call number and arguments (like a mock)?

Here the working code, the file `package/my_file.py` with the function

```py
from typing import Callable, List

def generate_calls(function_to_call: Callable, arguments_to_give: List[int]):
    for an_argument in arguments_to_give:
        function_to_call(arg_1=an_argument)
```

Test file:

```py
from package.my_file import generate_calls


def test_call_with_arguments(mocker):
   a_list = [1, 2, 3]
   called_function = mocker.patch('package.my_file.Callable')
   generate_calls(called_function, a_list)
   # get the argument of the mock function when called
   argument_dict = [one_call[1] for one_call in called_function.call_args_list]
   assert argument_dict == [{'arg_1': 1}, {'arg_1': 2}, {'arg_1': 3}]
```

Comment: What is `mocker`? You shouldn't need to mock `Callable` at all, precisely *because* it isn't used at run time.

Comment: `mocker` is a fixture coming from the [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) package. I need to check what are the argument given to the function which a simple function cannot give me (or I miss something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in a MagicMock object directly into `generate_calls` in your test. Use a pattern like the following

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def call_with_1(fun):
    fun(1)

def test_called():
    mock_fun = MagicMock()
    call_with_1(mock_fun)
    mock_fun.assert_called_with(1)
    assert mock_fun.call_count == 1
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is more (or less) Pythonic than what the OP already has (unless you count "using standard libraries" as more Pythonic than using 3rd-party libraries).

Comment: Exactly what I need and really simple. It avoids me to mock a typing function (which was the unpythonic part). Thanks a lot.